# Django allauth: Getting an IntegrityError during user creation

Tags: django-allauth

I saw a few discussions relating to this, but it seems the common cause of this is entering `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD=None`, which I'm not doing.

The exact error is:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key" DETAIL: Key (username)=(testaccount) already exists.
```

(It doesn't, at least not when I fill out the form. Despite the error, it then shows up in my database, which leads me to believe it's making the account twice.)

Here are my custom allauth settings:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED=True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD='username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION=True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION=True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'profiles.forms.UserCreateForm'
```

And, just in case, here's my form:

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Update: I've been trying to fix this for 2 weeks now and my code has undergone a lot of iterations. This seems to be the minimal amount of code I can have and still reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had an integrityerror because my existing users had identical usernames before I started implementing this (I use PostgreSQL). In this case you might have multiple users with username 'testaccount'.
Maybe you should try to delete your existing users or make sure usernames are unique.